# Import CSV file with escaped quotes via "Table Data Import Wizard" of MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, csv, mysql-workbench

I have a CSV with the following content

```
160,Some String,"Some description ""for a text"", which can't be imported",2,263,10000
```

The *Table Data Import Wizard* of *MySQL Workbench* seems not be able to handle **double quotes**. I tried with `\"` and `"""` but everytime it fails with

> Error
>   Unhandled exception: list index out of range
>   Check the log for more details.

So is there a possibility to change the CSV content to an escape character *MySQL Workbench* understands? This I could use to adapt my VBA script (so the idea).

I'm using MySQL Workbench 8.0 (8.0.17 build 14960816).

**Edit:**

Here is a sample CSV content, where the import fails.

```
160,160,Lorem,"Lorem, ipsum, lorem ""Lorem ipsum"". Lorem, ipsum, Lorem ipsum.",2,263,10000
170,170,Ipsum,"Lorem ""Lorem ipsum"" Lorem 37,5°C Ipsum. Lorem ipsum",3,361,10000
```

Comment: Is the content in a single column?

Comment: @James: Structure is like `id,name,information,level,rank,release`. So the string with the escaped quotes is in a single column: *Some description "for a text", which can't be imported*

Comment: Okay, so in the excel the records are placed only in column A? If so, have you tried text to columns and tried it? Or just share the sample csv format so that can look into it.

Comment: If the data is separated by column it works fine  for me.

Comment: There is a VBA script, which writes the data in different columns. Then the worksheet is exported as CSV. If this CSV is opened with Excel (without the data import tool) the data is indeed in one column. I've added a sample to the question. It must be a combination of `"` and `,` I think, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: @James: It definitely brakes at the text `37,5`, when there is an escape quote `""` text before. The same is valid for the first line! So there can't be another `,` in between the quotes `"` if the separator is `,` and escape quotes `""` are used.

Comment: Have you tried converting from text to columns in excel then import?

Comment: What do you mean by that? The data is in separate columns. Then I use `Copy`, `SaveAs FileFormat:=xlCSV` together with `Close` to save it as CSV.

Comment: Then attach the .csv file here

Comment: I can't attach the resulting CSV file here, because it contains licensed material ... Isn't the sample content in the question sufficient? Put the values in separate columns and then you can write your VBA script.

Comment: Since i have changed the sample file from single column into individual column  based on comma separation and tried import it works fine.

Comment: Now I found a solution for my problem (see the answer). You brought me on the idea. Thanks for your help and time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I use this command for exporting to CSV

```
workbookExport.SaveAs Filename:=CSVFilename, FileFormat:=xlCSV, local:=True
```

it does work now. Through `local:=True` my region delimiter `;` is used. Accordingly, I don't have problems with escape quotes `""` together with the delimiter `,` anymore. The issue occurred under the following condition:

Between a quoted text e.g.

> "Lorem ipsum ""Lorem Ipsum"" lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum"

there is an escaped text sequence (*Lorem Ipsum*). Afterwards there is a comma (`,`), but this is still between the quoted text.

Here the system struggles with the default limiter `,` between columns and the comma in the quoted text. Using another a semicolon `;` as delimiter solves the problem, because he can now differentiate between the individual columns.

If you export an xls(x) to CSV the semicolon seems to be default delimiter for my set region. But with my VBA export I needed to do the above changes.

Comment: Yup, thanks for pointing that out. Using ";" as a delimiter instead of "," seems to be fixing the issue for me as well. Cheers!